# How to create a voltage divider for different (changing in time) loads?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, voltage-divider, virtual-ground

What I need basically is to create a -12V - 0V - 12V power supply from a 0 - 24V DC supply.

The problem is I can't just make a voltage divider because the loads on each part is changing in time. I tried adding the largest capacitors I have (two 4700 µF) but it is clearly not enough, loads can vary quite much and drive huge currents (it can go up to around 10 Amps)...

Is there simple way I can make a circuit a stable  0 V -12 V and 0 V +12 V form this supply? I don't mind if voltages are slightly below 12 V (can afford a 0.7 V decrease due to transistors for instance) but what is very important is to have a stable symmetric DC voltage.

Comment: You're looking for a "rail splitter": https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=rail+splitter  At high currents, consider an SMPS: a synchronous buck fixed to near 50% duty is equivalent to the op-amp case, without the losses of a linear amplifier.

Answer (score 3):

Considering just one half of the dual supply, a linear implementation would use some regulating element (a transistor, probably) to "drop" 12V, which it does by varying its own impedance to match the load, thus maintaining an equal (12V) drop across itself and load:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWFlu9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The problem here is that for currents of 10A through the load, those same 10A must pass through the regulating element too. With 10A through it, and 12V across it, the regulator itself will dissipate power:

$$ P=IV = 10A \times 12V = 120W $$

That's going to require some extreme heat-sinking and forced-air cooling to prevent it from overheating. Also, it's likely you will need multiple pass transistors to share that load, which further complicates matters.

Admittedly, this is a worst case scenario, and since you'd probably be using a push-pull pair to maintain that 12V midpoint (fake ground), it's likely that the other load (across the other 12V "pseudo" supply) will bear some of that burden. Still, you have to plan for worst case conditions.

With such a heavy load, you'll probably need a switching solution, employing DC-DC converters. The setup might resemble this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fww4tA.png)</sup>

You could also use two buck converters, but then you must ensure that at least one of them is completely electrically isolated between output and input, otherwise you will short-circuit something when you connect their outputs in series. Both converters will obviously need to be able to produce 10A.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to create is a thing called a 'virtual ground'. Basically, you take the midpoint reference of 24V and buffer it to make it 'stiff'.

Here's an answer with a collection of approaches which may be scaled up to high current: [How to increase the output current of a dual supply (virtual ground) circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/561211/how-to-increase-the-output-current-of-a-dual-supply-virtual-ground-circuit/561220#561220)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have boils down to the fact that you have two terminals on the power supply, so essentially anything that flows out of one terminal must flow back into the other.  Therefore if you’re drawing 10A on one of your 12V rails you have to pass the same through the other somehow.  An analogue solution might attempt to dissipate any current differential as heat using some kind of current mirror arrangement, although that would be very inefficient.  These days a DC-DC converter is relatively easy to implement and would offer much better efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a ground reference voltage divider which serves as the + input to a high powered op amp, with the output fed back to the - input.  This is a unity gain buffer which will keep your ground relatively stable, by shunting current through the op amp itself to keep the ground at the correct voltage.  You need to find an op amp that works off of 24V and supplies enough current to keep your ground from getting pulled around by other currents.  Other forms of unity gain buffer will work as well.

Alternatively, you could put a 12V regulator across the 24V supply, and use the output as ground.

Answer (score 0):

## Need for philosophy

When people want to understand something (virtual ground), they look to science (circuit design) for help. If they do not get a satisfactory enough answer, they look for it in philosophy... and if they do not find it there either, they look for help in religion. I think we have already exhausted the first option and it is time for the second (hopefully we will not have to use the third).

## Basic idea

### Virtual zero

There is hardly anything more absurd than to destroy the energy of a "negative" source through the energy of a "positive" source to get a zero result... but still we sometimes do it. Here is one of many examples.

Imagine that it is winter and a heater has raised the temperature in the room to 20°. However, for some reason we want a temperature of 0°. The logical thing to do is to turn off or turn down the heater; but if for some reason we can't do it there is also a faster but illogical (uneconomical) way - to open the window. An even more illogical way is to turn on a cooler at -20° to make the temperature 0°; this is an example of a "thermal virtual zero".

So the idea of *virtual zero* is ***to neutralize an energy source with an opposite energy source, thus wasting twice as much energy***.

### Virtual ground

In electrical circuits, this phenomenon occurs between interacting voltage sources. In this configuration, two grounded voltage sources (V1 and V2) of opposite polarity are connected in parallel through resistors R1 and R2, and it is fulfilled V2/V1 = -R2/R1. As a result, the voltage of the middle point between the resistors is zero (*virtual ground*). In fact, the two voltage sources are connected in series on the R1-R2 network and their voltages are summed (R1-R2 network can be considered as a *resistor summing circuit with weighted inputs*). Figuratively speaking, there is something like a "tug of war" between the two sources connected through a "pull-up" and "pull-down" resistors. The same current flows through both sources and both resistors dissipate power (like in the analogy above). In the simplest implementation, the two voltage sources and the two resistors are constant.

## Op-amp implementations

So this configuration is reasonable to use only for low-current (signal) applications such as an *op-amp inverting amplifier* where the virtual ground is an internal point and used for its own needs. Here, the resistors have a high resistance and the power dissipated by them is negligible. In this implementation, the two voltage sources are varying and the two resistors are constant.

An even simpler example is the "ideal" current-to-voltage ammeter aka "transimpedance amplifier". It consists of only one resistor R acting as a *current-to-voltage converter* and an op-amp that destroys the voltage drop VR = I*R across the resistor by adding the same voltage VR. As a result, the resulting voltage is VR - VR = 0 V (virtual ground), and the whole circuit acts just as a "piece of wire". It seems to be the perfect ammeter, and yet it is not used in multimeters for measuring high currents. The reason is the same - all the current goes through the op-amp output. This is why a simple resistor is still used in multemeters acting as ammeters.

## Power implementations

We can see the "tugging of war" *pull-up & pull-down* pair also in the power *push-pull* buffers providing a strong virtual ground. It appears at the buffer output that can both source and sink current, and its input is grounded (i.e. it acts as a *zero voltage follower* or *zero voltage stabilizer*). Here the virtual ground is used for external needs.

In this implementation, the two voltage sources are constant but some of the "pulling" elements (transistors) are varying. If we group everything connected to the virtual ground as a "load", we can see in total three such pairs connected to the virtual ground:

- "pulling up" NPN transistor Q1 and "pulling down" load (power is wasted in Q1),
- "pulling down" PNP transistor Q2 and "pulling up" load (power is wasted in Q2), and
- "pulling up" NPN transistor Q1 and "pulling down PNP transistor Q2 (when the load does not "pull" the virtual ground); power is wasted both in Q1 and Q2.

Let's consider the circuit operation in terms of currents:

- When the load sinks more current from the virtual ground, its voltage tries to decrease. Q1 reacts to this intervention by decreasing its "resistance" thus sourcing more current to the virtual ground. As a result, its voltage does not "move".
- When the load sources more current to the virtual ground, its voltage tries to increase. Now Q2 reacts to this intervention by decreasing its "resistance" thus sinking more current from the virtual ground. As a result, its voltage does not "move".
- If the load does not source/sink current to/from the virtual ground, both Q1 and Q2 are semiconductive (because of the biasing in this class AB amplifier stage), and the same current flows through them. The output voltage does not "move".

## Summary

Finally, let's summarize all this wisdom in a few conclusions:

- The basic idea of ​​this phenomenon is to obtain a zero value by destroying the energy produced by a "negative source" by an equivalent in value energy of a "positive source".
- This results in energy consumption from both sources.
- The virtual ground configuration consists of two grounded voltage sources (V1 and V2) of opposite polarity that are connected in parallel through resistors R1 and R2 so that V2/V1 = -R2/R1.
- In the simplest applications, the two voltage sources and resistors are constant.
- In more sophisticated applications, some of them can be varying.
- The virtual ground configuration is reasonable to use only for low-current (signal) applications, for internal needs.
- In high-current applications, a real ground (two opposite polarity voltage sources) must be used.
- The virtual ground in these power applications is the output of a power buffer with a grounded input (zero voltage follower) that can both source and sink current. Here the virtual ground is used for external needs (by other circuits).
- In this configuration, half of the power is useful and consumed by the load;  the remaining half is wasted in the opposite  "pulling" element.

*(I can't make CircuitLab simulations right now. See also a [related answer of mine](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/678066/61398))*.